# Duplicated params value on GA4 event

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, event-tracking

I'm facing a strange issue that drove my crazy.the page_view event on GA4 contains some duplicated param's value for example sometimes the page title is getting the previous page and the current page titles together in the same page_title param. check the attached screenshot

Click to check the screenshot

[image: 1]

i create multiple GA4 accounts and try to send custom events but without any result

Answer (score 0):

That seems to me like the way GA's debugger reports batched events. And since it's a page_view, I presume it's an SPA since batching doesn't work through real page loads. See the `Events Grouping` section [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9322688?hl=en#zippy=%2Crealtime-report%2Cdebugview-report) for more.

Anyhow, you don't want to look at GA's debugger too much. Maybe only to confirm the data structure you're sending is the data structure it's receiving. For any other debugging you should do it locally, either by looking at the raw network requests in the Network tab or by using Adswerve's dataLayer explorer extension. You will be able to see event batching there.